# boost string type mismatch

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

In the followring code,

```
class MonitorResult {
public:
    void putDir(std::string && dir) { }
};

void listDir(boost::filesystem::path && dir, MonitorResult & result) {

    for(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it(dir);
        it != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); ++it) {
        if(boost::filesystem::is_symlink( it->path()) ) {
            continue;
        }
        else if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(it->path())) {
            result.putDir(it->path().string() );  // Error here
        }
    }
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to `MonitorResult::putDir(const string&)`
>      candidate is `void MonitorResult::putDir(std::string&&)`

I am not getting `std::string`, but just `string`. How can type error be resolved? Thanks.

Comment: the boost filesystem path class `string()` function returns by const value or const& you can't bind that result to a string&&. Just use `void putDir(const std::string & dir) { }`. (there's also a template member function "string" of path that will return by value but that is for converting to custom string types)

Comment: `(T &&)` in the function signature is an anti-pattern, and you have faced one of the reasons. If you need a copy of the argument, declare `(T)`, otherwise declare `(T const &)`.

Comment: why the error is not  `const std::string&`?